# Mule: Setting session variable inside an invoke component

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Best way to set a session variable inside an invoke component used to call a spring bean specific method.

```
<invoke object-ref="serviceBean" method="asyncFlowMethod" doc:name="Invoke3" methodArguments="#[sessionVars['event']]"/>


public void asyncFlowMethod(String event) {

        Inside this method i need to set a session variable 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to change the method to receive the MuleMessage and use it to access the session variables:

```
public void asyncFlowMethod(MuleMessage message) {

        String event = message.getProperty("event", PropertyScope.SESSION);

        message.setProperty("event", event + "test", PropertyScope.SESSION);


    }
```

and invoke it using

```
<invoke object-ref="serviceBean" method="asyncFlowMethod" doc:name="Invoke3" methodArguments="#[message]"/>
```

Comment: #[message] is messagecontext and not MuleMessage

Comment: MessageContext outbound properties even if set in method are not visible outside that method.

Comment: @NAZARREHMAN Try the solution proposed by @DavidDossot in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976893/access-mule-message-from-arbitrary-place-in-a-thread), to access the **MuleEvent**  ``RequestContext.getEvent()``