# Access Mule Message from arbitrary place in a thread

Tags: java, mule

With Mule ESB, from an arbitrary class, is it possible to get a handle of the current mule message for that thread?
For example, if I create custom log4j appender, can it get access to the mule message and pull data from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using `RequestContext.getEvent().getMessage()` ([javadoc](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/RequestContext.html)).

And yes, it is deprecated, with this warning:

> If access to MuleEvent or MuleMessage is required, then implement a MessageProcessor or Callable instead

But this is not always possible. So using this static helper remains your best option.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give it a shot and report back.   Would it also be possible to implement MuleContextAware to have the context injected?

Comment: No, `MuleContextAware` would give you the `MuleContext`, not the `MuleEvent`/`MuleMessage`.

Comment: Thanks. My aim is to create a log4j Layout extending the pattern layout that will allow config to include the correlation id in the log pattern

Comment: My answer would work then, except if someone wraps your logger with an async appender, in which case the logging thread would be different than the Mule thread and the context would be lost. In any case, I think you could accept my answer at this point :)

Comment: everything's working perfectly, but I'm still a little uneasy that it's deprecated. What was the reason for deprecation. Is it safe to rely on for the future. The alternative of implementing MessageProcessor or Callable won't help this situation

Comment: I wish I knew the reason for deprecation. It's not related to the singletonization of the `MuleContext`. Maybe to avoid having to carry the `MuleEvent` from thread to thread to allow a future refactoring of Mule's codebase?

Comment: upgrading to 3.6 now. Apparently asynchronous http end points are added. Does this mean a single thread may have multiple request contexts? If so, it might explain why this is deprecated

Comment: It's been deprecated for a long time, unrelated to the new HTTP listener in 3.6.